# Python 2.7 & Pandas: How to replace values at 12:00 with values from 11:55?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a timeseries. The index is a type datetimeindex. The values are random values.

Timeseries I have:

```
2015-01-02 19:30:00-05:00    61
2015-01-02 19:35:00-05:00    63
2015-01-02 19:40:00-05:00    65
2015-01-05 19:30:00-05:00    38
2015-01-05 19:35:00-05:00    39
2015-01-05 19:40:00-05:00    34
2015-01-06 19:30:00-05:00    17
2015-01-06 19:35:00-05:00    18
2015-01-06 19:40:00-05:00    15
```

How do I explicitly say 'replace the values at 19:40:00 with the values at 19:35:00?

Timeseries I want:

```
2015-01-02 19:30:00-05:00    61
2015-01-02 19:35:00-05:00    63
2015-01-02 19:40:00-05:00    63
2015-01-05 19:30:00-05:00    38
2015-01-05 19:35:00-05:00    39
2015-01-05 19:40:00-05:00    39
2015-01-06 19:30:00-05:00    17
2015-01-06 19:35:00-05:00    18
2015-01-06 19:40:00-05:00    18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import datetime

times = ts.index.time
ts[times==datetime.time(19, 40)] = ts[times==datetime.time(19, 35)].values
```